# How to send Data to the client with out client requesting the ws server in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, web-services, csv

I  need to convert a csv file to json format and send it to a client requesting to ws server in nodejs ,

the file will be updated so many times so i need to send updated data  to client

i am able to send data once it is loaded completely(like when app is started it sends all data in file to client) but when i update data in the file the updated data is being printed out on console but it is not being sent to client is their any thing wrong in my code

my node.js code:

```
var ts = require('tail-stream');
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var converter = new Converter({constructResult:false}); //for big csv data

var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    // process HTTP request. Since we're writing just WebSockets server
    // we don't have to implement anything.
    response.write('hello');
    console.log('in http server \n');
});
server.listen(1337, function() { });

// create the server
wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

// WebSocket server
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
   var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

    console.log('wsserver');
    connection.send('ws server');

    converter.on("record_parsed", function (jsonObj) {
   console.log(jsonObj); //here is your result json object
   connection.send(jsonObj);

});


var tstream = ts.createReadStream('log.csv', {
    beginAt: 0,
    onMove: 'follow',
    detectTruncate: false,
    onTruncate: 'end',
    endOnError: false
});


tstream.pipe(converter);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are creating a new read stream and adding a listener to the converter on every new connection, that will cause trouble once you have more than one client (same event emitted multiple times, etc..). Instead of that you should keep just one reader and notify all open connections when there's a new record.

Also notice that the library you are using only accepts UTF-8 strings or binary type messages, row objects sent the way you're sending them now will be received as a "[object Object]" string after `toString()` is called on them. You should probably send just send the row string or use `JSON.stringify` / `JSON.parse`.

Try this:

```
var http            = require("http");
var tailStream      = require("tail-stream");
var Converter       = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var WebSocketServer = require("websocket").server;

var server    = http.createServer();
var wsServer  = new WebSocketServer({ httpServer: server });
var converter = new Converter({constructResult:false});
var logStream = tailStream.createReadStream("log.csv", { detectTruncate : false });

var connections = [];


server.listen(1337);
logStream.pipe(converter);


//----------------------------------------------------
converter.on("record_parsed", function (jsonObj) {

    connections.forEach(function(connection){
        connection.send(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
    });
});


//----------------------------------------------------
wsServer.on("request", function(request) {

   var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

   connection.on("close", function() {
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(connection), 1);
    });

   connections.push(connection);
});
```

The code above works, tested like this on the client side:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1337/');

socket.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(event.data));
}
```

Note: this doesn't send the whole content of the file at the beginning, just the updates, but you can easily achieve this storing the records and sending them on new connections.

Comment: can we send the updated records to the client already in connection with out new connections

Comment: my main question was that only weather we can send updated data to customer with out new connections or requests to server

Comment: Yes, and the code above is doing exactly that. You keep a socket open, no need for a new connection or request from the client.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933201/tail-stream-module-in-nodejs-is-not-printing-last-record-of-the-file

Comment: its not giving me the last record do you know the reason

Comment: Sure, will take a look into it in a couple of hours